# WebGL How to render simple 3D triangle

Tags: javascript, three.js

What I want to do:

Render a triangle with `(x, y, z)` points:

```
var v1 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
var v2 = new THREE.Vector3(600, 0, 0);
var v3 = new THREE.Vector3(300, 0, 600);
var v4 = new THREE.Vector3(300, 600, 300);
```

what I tried and does not work:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>My first Three.js app</title>
    <style>
        canvas {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <!-- <script src="../../Scripts/three.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://assignments-dot-udacity-extras.appspot.com/media/js/cs291/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://assignments-dot-udacity-extras.appspot.com/media/js/cs291/OrbitAndPanControls.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="container">
    <canvas width="846" height="494" style="width: 846px; height: 494px;">    </canvas>
    </div>


    <script>
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /*global THREE, window, document*/
    var camera, scene, renderer;
    var cameraControls;
    var clock = new THREE.Clock();

    function fillScene() {
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        // Triangle Mesh
        var material, geometry, mesh;
        material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
        geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        // Student: add a colored triangle here
        var v1 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        var v2 = new THREE.Vector3(600, 0, 0);
        var v3 = new THREE.Vector3(300, 0, 600);
        var v4 = new THREE.Vector3(300, 600, 300);

        geometry.vertices.push(v1);
        geometry.vertices.push(v2);
        geometry.vertices.push(v3);
        geometry.vertices.push(v4);

        geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2, 3));

        var color1 = new THREE.Color(0xFF0000);
        var color2 = new THREE.Color(0x00FF00);
        var color3 = new THREE.Color(0x0000FF);
        var color4 = new THREE.Color(0x0000FF);

        geometry.faces[0].vertexColors = [color1, color2, color3, color4];
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add(mesh);
    }

    function init() {
        var canvasWidth = 846;
        var canvasHeight = 494;
        var canvasRatio = canvasWidth / canvasHeight;
        // RENDERER
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
        renderer.gammaInput = true;
        renderer.gammaOutput = true;
        renderer.setSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        renderer.setClearColorHex(0xAAAAAA, 1.0);
        // CAMERA
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(55, canvasRatio, 1, 4000);
        camera.position.set(100, 150, 130);
        // CONTROLS
        console.log(renderer.domElement, THREE.OrbitAndPanControls);
        cameraControls = new THREE.OrbitAndPanControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        cameraControls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
    }

    function addToDOM() {
        var container = document.getElementById('container');
        var canvas = container.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
        if (canvas.length > 0) {
            container.removeChild(canvas[0]);
        }
        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    }

    function animate() {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        render();
    }

    function render() {
        var delta = clock.getDelta();
        cameraControls.update(delta);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    try {
        init();
        fillScene();
        addToDOM();
        animate();
    } catch (e) {
        var errorReport =
            "Your program encountered an unrecoverable error, can not draw on canvas. Error was:<br/><br/>";
        $('#container').append(errorReport + e);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Copy/Paste my code, you will get this error:

> Unhandled exception at line 30, column 5 in http://localhost:5167/Home/Index
>
> 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'THREE' is undefined

Comment: A triangle with 4 points!? `THREE` refers to the three.js library. Apparently the three.js library is missing, you should load it correctly.

Comment: it's working properly on my side. Although the CDN links are a little bit slow, so it may timeout the HTTP requests while downloading the js files. Try testing the urls in your browser,  just to see if you can access them at all. It could as well be a proxy issue.

Comment: As @wilt says, a triangle should have 3 points. The fourth parameter that you are passing is a normal, and if you are setting it, it should be an unitary vector